# Understanding OrientGraphFactory

Tags: orientdb

I do not understand the OrientGraphFactory class fully. Several questions:

1) What is the role of leaveGraphsOpen ? I cannot see any usage and/or examples.

```
public class OrientGraphFactory extends ... {

    public boolean isLeaveGraphsOpen() {
      return leaveGraphsOpen;
    }

    public void setLeaveGraphsOpen(boolean leaveGraphsOpen) {
      this.leaveGraphsOpen = leaveGraphsOpen;
    }

}
```

2) Why two *public* getDatabase() methods? This is a factory for *Graph databases*

3) I only want to auto create the database in specific situations (in our app, only when in "setting up mode". The only way to achieve this is:

```
final boolean autoCreate = false;
this.factory = new OrientGraphFactory(url) {

    @Override
    public ODatabaseDocumentTx getDatabase(boolean iCreate, boolean iOpen) {
        return super.getDatabase(autoCreate, iOpen);
    }

}.setupPool(1, 5); // default: no pool (instances are created on demand)
```

Is this the correct way of doing this? Looks very ugly :(

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported out of the box, so your solution should work and use the wonderful Object Orientation.

Comment: 1) Where did you find "leaveGraphsOpen"? 2) Because we use the underlying Document Database instance.

Comment: See my updated question. Thanks for answering this too! About 2): Yes i Know and that is clear. Question puts emphasis on *public* API.

Comment: You're right, there is no much sense to leave it public. Please could you open an issue for that?